# Boolean Operations on Cairo Paths?

Tags: graphics, path, vector, 2d, cairo

Is there any way to build paths in Cairo by combining two paths together through Boolean operations such as Union, Difference, and Intersection? I'm working on a vector graphics application that uses Cairo to do its rendering and would like to give my users the ability to combine paths together in this manner, but I can't find a way to do it in Cairo.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a way to do this with the cairo libraries.  But it's a feature I've been looking for too.  Would definitely be helpful when (for example) stroking the combination of two paths - compositing operators mentioned by ntd don't seem to be able to do this.

In the meantime, I'm trying to write scripts for inkscape, and letting inkscape do the unioning/differencing.  Acceptable for the problem I'm working on but definitely not for yours.  Have you had any luck, either with cairo or any other svg library?  After a couple days of googling, it doesn't seem to be trivial :/

Comment: ps - path intersect/combine/overlay is listed on the cairo site as a possible summer-of-code project  http://cairographics.org/summerofcode/ideas/

Answer (score 0):

Combining paths with operators does not make any sense to me. What do you get from "line AND curve OR arc"?

Instead, you can apply [compositing operators](http://cairographics.org/operators/) by using `cairo_set_operator()`: it will set how the current drawing operation (being it `cairo_fill()`, `cairo_stroke()` or whatever) should be mixed with the old content of the surface.

Comment: An example of what I mean is the way Inkscape combines paths through boolean operations: http://www.usinginkscape.com/node/34. I suppose most of those effects could be achieved through a series of compositing operators, except that places where the two figures' paths intersect wouldn't necessarily have proper line joins.

Comment: I still don't understand the question: inkscape itself uses cairo since version 0.46: http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/0.46#Speed_and_interactivity